# Building GCC cross-compiler for PowerPC AIX 7.1

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling

I'm just trying to build gcc cross-compiler for AIX7.1. Have successfully built binutils-2.25.1, but have problems with building gcc-6.3.0. It successfully compile target **all-gcc** but fails on compiling **all-target-libgcc**. I get this error:

```
In file included from /home/zakkurasov/aix-sysroot/usr/include/sys/inttypes.h:51:0,
             from /home/zakkurasov/cross-aix/build-gcc/gcc/include-fixed/sys/types.h:70,
             from /home/zakkurasov/cross-aix/build-gcc/gcc/include-fixed/stdio.h:489,
             from ../../../../gcc-6.3.0/libgcc/../gcc/tsystem.h:87,
             from ../../../../gcc-6.3.0/libgcc/libgcc2.c:27:
/home/zakkurasov/cross-aix/build-gcc/gcc/include/stdint.h:9:26: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
 # include_next <stdint.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:467: recipe for target '_lshrdi3.o' failed
make[4]: *** [_lshrdi3.o] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/zakkurasov/cross-aix/build-gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/pthread/libgcc'
Makefile:1161: recipe for target 'multi-do' failed
make[3]: *** [multi-do] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/zakkurasov/cross-aix/build-gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/libgcc'
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'all-multi' failed
make[2]: *** [all-multi] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/zakkurasov/cross-aix/build-gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/libgcc'
Makefile:12321: recipe for target 'all-target-libgcc' failed
make[1]: *** [all-target-libgcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/zakkurasov/cross-aix/build-gcc'
Makefile:882: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Configure with command:

```
../gcc-6.3.0/configure --prefix=$PREFIX --host=$MACHTYPE --build=$MACHTYPE --target=$TARGET --with-sysroot=$SYSROOT --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --enable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++ -v
```

where

```
$PREFIX=/opt/aix
$TARGET=powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0
$MACHTYPE=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
$SYSROOT contain includes and libs from AIX 7.1
```

Sorry, have checked and saw that files in $SYSROOT/usr just broken symbolic links. Replaced it with files, and get new error:

```
/home/zakkurasov/cross-aix/build-gcc/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/zakkurasov/cross-aix/build-gcc/./gcc/ -B/opt/aix/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/bin/ -B/opt/aix/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/lib/ -isystem /opt/aix/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/include -isystem /opt/aix/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/sys-include    -g -O2 -maix64 -O2  -g -O2 -DIN_GCC  -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE  -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition  -isystem ./include   -mlong-double-128 -g -DIN_LIBGCC2 -fbuilding-libgcc -fno-stack-protector   -mlong-double-128 -I. -I. -I../../.././gcc -I../../../../gcc-6.3.0/libgcc -I../../../../gcc-6.3.0/libgcc/. -I../../../../gcc-6.3.0/libgcc/../gcc -I../../../../gcc-6.3.0/libgcc/../include  -DHAVE_CC_TLS -DUSE_EMUTLS -o _mulsc3.o -MT _mulsc3.o -MD -MP -MF _mulsc3.dep -DL_mulsc3 -c ../../../../gcc-6.3.0/libgcc/libgcc2.c 
/tmp/ccuoaSIc.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccuoaSIc.s:545: Error: junk at end of line: `4'
/tmp/ccuoaSIc.s:548: Error: junk at end of line: `1'
Makefile:467: recipe for target '_mulsc3.o' failed
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++. [Some C and C++ question guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360824/584518).

Comment: The error itself explains what the problem is, `/home/zakkurasov/cross-aix/build-gcc/gcc/include/stdint.h:9:26: fatal error: stdint.h: ` No such file or directory? try to locate the stdint.h file and give the correct path of that file.

Comment: The actual issue here is with GNU Binutils.  GCC emits code that uses XCOFF symbol visibility, but GNU as doesn't have support for it.  There is a bug for it here: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22085